# solana keygen with Seed phrase in JSON file

Tags: solana-keygen

I am trying to create a vanity solana pubkey using the command with qualifiers like this:

> solana-keygen grind --starts-with 1:1 --ignore-case --use-mnemonic --word-count 12

So far so good and it will take a short while to get the command executed, as I am defining only one character.

Now my headache is that I want to have the pubkey start with a specific **five-letter** combination which I realize will take AGES to find, particularly since I am asking for mnemonic.

I plan on going away and leave the computer running for the three weeks I am away to give it time to search. Thing is that once a key is found the mnemonic will show on the terminal window. My worry is that IF there was a power outage then the info will be lost and I have to start over again.

Is there a way to have the terminal print the mnemonic into a file, similar to how the secret passcode gets printed into a json file?

Thank you!
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Success!

After some further digging I found a solution and thought I would share for those who may have a similar issue.

You can print the info into a text file which will save along with the json file. Just add two chevrons (greater than) and a name of the text file you want (I chose mnemonics.txt) at the end of your command: >> mnemonics.txt

Using my example:

solana-keygen grind --starts-with 1:1 --ignore-case --use-mnemonic --word-count 12 >> mnemonics.txt

Happy grinding!
R